# Math functions to log an object based on a random number

Tags: javascript, undefined, console.log

I want to get a the current value of something based one if the Math function is a 0, 1 or 2. Sometimes it does just want i wrote it to do. Using Quokka i can see what it logs but one of two bugs happen when it doesn't execute properly. Either it logs "Cannot read property 'answers' of Undefined" or it will log the same value even though the value of random() has changed. I just want to figure out why its behaving this way.

```
function question(q, answersArr) {
        this.question = q,
        this.answers = answersArr
}

let questionOne = new question("Question One?", ["Answer One", "Answer Two", "Answer Three"]);
let questionTwo = new question("Question Two?", ["Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six"]);
let questionThree = new question("Question Three?", ["Answer Seven", "Answer Eight", "Answer Nine"]);

let questionArr = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];

let random = function() {
    let randoNum = Math.random() * 3;
    let roundedNum = Math.floor(randoNum);
    return roundedNum
};

console.log(random());

let current;
if (random() === 0) {
    current = array['0']
} else if (random() === 1) {
    current = array["1"]
} else if (random() === 2) {
    current = array['2']
}

console.log(current.answers);
console.log(current);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `random()`, you're generating a *new* random number. So, if by chance each random number does not match the current number you're testing against, `current` will never be assigned to.

Call `random()` only once, save it in a variable, and then check that variable.

You also have to reference the question array's name, which is `questionArr`, not `array`.

```js
function question(q, answersArr) {
        this.question = q,
        this.answers = answersArr
}

let questionOne = new question("Question One?", ["Answer One", "Answer Two", "Answer Three"]);
let questionTwo = new question("Question Two?", ["Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six"]);
let questionThree = new question("Question Three?", ["Answer Seven", "Answer Eight", "Answer Nine"]);

let questionArr = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];

let random = function() {
    let randoNum = Math.random() * 3;
    let roundedNum = Math.floor(randoNum);
    return roundedNum
};

const randIndex = random();
console.log(randIndex);

let current;
if (randIndex === 0) {
    current = questionArr['0']
} else if (randIndex === 1) {
    current = questionArr["1"]
} else if (randIndex === 2) {
    current = questionArr['2']
}

console.log(current.answers);
console.log(current);
```

In addition, your code can be significantly trimmed down, if you want:

```js
function question(q, answersArr) {
        this.question = q,
        this.answers = answersArr
}
const questionOne = new question("Question One?", ["Answer One", "Answer Two", "Answer Three"]);
const questionTwo = new question("Question Two?", ["Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six"]);
const questionThree = new question("Question Three?", ["Answer Seven", "Answer Eight", "Answer Nine"]);
const questionArr = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
const randIndex = random();
console.log(randIndex);
const current = questionArr[randIndex];
console.log(current.answers);
console.log(current);
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you i see now why i didnt work. But this code was part of a larger function that i didnt post the rest of so array's value was questionArr.